# Best Timer Designs for Java2D video games

Tags: java, timer, java-2d

I am building a Java2D video game with multiple sprites updating on the screen at once, and was looking for feedback with regard to best way to handle updates via use of Timers.

I was looking for feedback on best way to handle Timer design that would update locations of each Sprite.  Currently, the way I have been doing it, is I have one Timer.  When it expires, I update the position of each Sprite.  I only ever Update Sprite location by 1 pixel, to keep motion smooth.  If something was to update slower that then rest of the Sprite, I update it's position say on every 3 or 5th call of a getImage() call (used to get the current icon image of the sprite).

Now with this approach, all updates are dependent on the main timer, and the Sprites sort of update in relation to each other.  So if I wanted to speed up the game, I just update the refresh rate of the main timer.

However, I don't know if this is the best approach.  Would it be better to put each object on it's own timer, but would that cause other issues?  Maybe cause problems for the main paint() method?

Was just looking for feedback on a good design technique for this.

Comment: Why are you not using a game engine, such as libgdx? You wouldn't need to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: @lbalazscs Maybe the OP wants to learn?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to keep using one timer while having perfectly smooth animations despite different animation and movement speeds between different sprites. The way to do is by changing your animation and movement of sprites from a tick based approach (move x many pixels per update) to a time based approach (move x many pixels per how much time has elapsed since the last update).

This would mean your Sprite class (or whatever you have), has floating point x and y positions, as well as floating point x and y velocities. To change the speed of a certain sprite, you would change the velocity (which would be pixels/drawingUnitsEtc per millisecond/nanosecond), and won't be limited by how fast you can make the timer run.

> However, I don't know if this is the best approach. Would it be better to put each object on it's own timer, but would that cause other issues?

Well if you did use a timer per Sprite that used a different speed, you would run into overhead problems if the timers ran on their own thread, and if the timers were executed on the same thread then you are technically updating your Sprites based on how much time has elapsed but just moving the velocity constant to an integer.

You would also run into a problem of how you can ensure the Timer consistently returns. With separate timers, imagine that there may be two sprites that are walking next to each other in game which want to update at 10ms, but one of them is running at 11ms due to a laggy timer, eventually one will run into the back of the other and turn around and mess up your level design or some other game mechanic. Another one is that they could be two Sprites of the same kind but now one is now an animation frame ahead of the other while that didn't hold true for the first few seconds that you saw them. With a single timer that updates all sprites that operate together you'll get those consistent results.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using java.util.timer's schedule method.
You could use the scheduleAtFixedRate method for cleaner looking code.
Only use one instance of Timer and attach all sprites to it, this keeps all sprites running on the same thread because then you eliminate all forms of concurrent modification, using a new thread for each sprite is way overkill as the threads will be running as fast as possible and maxing out the computer.

You could also simply make something along the lines of a SpriteManager class which extends Thread so that you don't even need to use timer, all sprites will be running as fast as possible but on one thread, it wont put too much load on the cpu but it worth it. Professionally, movement falls under physics so a game would have some physics thread that handles all updates to everything.

You could get even more detailed in the physics thread by realising that throughout the course of gameplay the amount of objects on the thread will change therefore will update less frequently making everything slower (even if it is microseconds). To keep everything running smoothly you can delta scale. Delta scaling simply takes the time it took last frame as a hint to how fast the thread is running and scales the speed of objects up or down appropriately - this is how (most) games don't run slower when the frame rate drops, instead, they look like they jumped to where it would be at that point in time.

Comment: Hi Lee, have some questions here about your approaches.

Comment: With regard to use of delta scaling, is there code posted online with regard to how to do this?  Now, I am having a problem with at times a flashing/blinking screen.  I have not investigated this yet.  I have a lot of dynamic things going on, so I doubt I am getting my screen refreshed at a constant interval.  Could this cause the screen to at times blink or flash?

Comment: Your question about the flashing screen isn't related to this, I can only recommend making another question here so we can see the code. You should know what it might be by knowing when it started. As for delta scaling algorithm I found [this](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/06/18/guest-tutorial-delta-time-in-corona/)